# newclude has destroyed my application

Tags: errors, include, auxiliary-files

I added

```
\usepackage{newclude}
```

with commands such as

```
\include*{myfile}
```

in an attempt to include myfile without the concomitant `\clearpage`. This didn't work, so I removed this new code and returned my tex file back to the same state it was in before. Now it won't compile! I keep getting the following error message:

```
! Undefined control sequence.

\@auxtag{myfile}{%
```

What the heck is going on??

Comment: Delete all *.aux, *.toc files and so on and try again.

Answer (score 5):

Delete all `*.aux`, `*.toc` and other auxiliary files and run LaTeX again. Some packages write control sequences to these files that become unknown once the package is no longer loaded.